# Keras - Replicating 1D tensor to create 3D tensor

Tags: python, keras

I'm currently trying to design a generator model which take input image and the conditional label concatenated in the image.

The input image is in 3D (including channel), while the label is in 1D (containing idx of the class)

```
input_image = Input(shape=(row, col, chann))
cond = Input(shape=(1,))
```

Based on info of [Concatenate](https://keras.io/layers/merge/), I need to reshape `cond` to be in same shape of `input_image`. But as far as I found on Keras docs, there's only [`RepeatVector`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector) that repeats 2D tensor into 3D.

How do I replicate the `cond` input to be in the same shape so I can concatenate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `Reshape` and `RepeatVector`

```
input_image = Input(shape=(row, col, chann))
cond = Input(shape=(1,))
cond = Reshape((row,col,1))(RepeatVector(row*col)(cond))
concat = Concatenate()([input_image, cond])
```

Comment: Then how do you replicate 2D tensor to be 3D tensor? Like replicating one-hot vector to be in shape of image `(row, col)` for concatenating it?