# Depth-wise concatenate in Keras

Tags: python, keras, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to depth-wise concat (example of implementation in [StarGAN](https://github.com/yunjey/stargan/blob/master/model.py#L58) using Pytorch) a one-hot vector into an image input, say

```
input_img = Input(shape = (row, col, chann))
one_hot = Input(shape = (7, ))
```

I stumbled on the same problem before ([it was class indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116732/keras-replicating-1d-tensor-to-create-3d-tensor)), and so I used RepeatVector+Reshape then Concatenate. But I found RepeatVector is not compatible when you want to repeat 3D into 4D (included `batch_num`).

How do I implement this method in Keras? I found that `Upsampling2D` could do the works, but I don't know if it able to keep the one-hot vector structure during upsampling process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an idea from [How to use tile function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250533/how-to-use-tile-function-in-keras) that you can use `tile`, but you need to reshape your `one_hot` to have the same number of dimensions with `input_img`

```
one_hot = Reshape((1, 1, 6))(one_hot)
one_hot = Lambda(K.tile, arguments = {'n' : (-1, row, col, 1)})(one_hot)
model_input = Concatenate()([input_img, one_hot])
```